# Can't delete folder after using RoboCopy

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I was trying to copy a file out of a folder and then afterward delete the folder. I'm using RoboCopy on windows 10.

Now I realize I could use the /MOVE switch but I ran into an error doing it the first way I was trying and I'd like to figure it out just so I have the knowledge of why it's happening.

I have a folder structure like so:

```
ParentFolder
---->SubFolder
-------->test.txt
---->test.bat
```

From within ParentFolder I run test.bat which contains the following script

```
echo off
setlocal
set dir="path\to\ParentFolder"
cd %dir%
robocopy %dir% %dir%\.. test.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 8 (
    rmdir /s /q "%dir%"
)
endlocal
```

The copy works fine, without the rmdir, the file copies and the old file is left within SubFolder. When I add the rmdir line, the copy still works fine, the old file is actually deleted, but then when it tries to remove the SubFolder directory I get the error that the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

So the final structure looks like this instead of having SubFolder removed:

```
ParentFolder
---->SubFolder
---->test.bat
---->test.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo off
setlocal
set dir="path\to\ParentFolder"
cd %dir%
robocopy %dir% %dir%\.. test.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 8 (
    cd\
    rmdir /s /q "%dir%"
)
endlocal
```

I think the problem is that you're trying to delete the folder while inside it.

See this example

```
cd c:\temp\test
rmdir /s /q c:\temp\test
cd c:\temp
rmdir /s /q c:\temp\test
```

[image]

As you can see the first `rmdir` failed but the second succeeded.

Comment: Oh my gosh. Of course it's so obvious! Thanks a lot!